# In notepad how to use shortcut CTRL+/ to comment AND comment out? (and if possible go to the next line)

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

I had some setting in Notepad++ that allowed me to comment and comment out selected records with the same shortcut 'CTRL+/', when language was set to sql. Mybe also in other languages by the way, I'm not sure. I think I had a plugin for that, but I can't find it anymore, and the previous virtual machine where I had it, does not exist anymore.

I guess I even asked this question somewhere before on stackoverflow, or found it here somewhere, but I can't find it (anymore) in stackoverflow...

Can anyone help me in getting my Notepad++ accept 'CTRL+/' as both 'comment' AND 'comment out'?

PS: I know of the Run/Modify shorcut(...)/Main menu/Single Line Comment and Single line Uncomment setting, and that that stand is CTRL+K and CTRL+SHIFT+K. Adjusting those to CTRL+/ does satisfy my desire that I can use ONE key combination to do do both (at least on my machine after I changed both to CTRL+/ , lines are only 'commented'.

Maybe something can be written with the following logic: if no '--' at start of line where cursor is, then add '--' at start of line; if '--' at start of line then replace '--' with ''.

PS2: what would be even better is if after pressing CTR+/ and the line is commented or commented out, that the cursor then goes to the next line (down). I think I had it like that... Any help is much appreciated(!).

I have Notepad++ 7.6.4 64 bit b.t.w., on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: `Ctrl+Q` should toggle comments on/off doesn't go to the next line though

Comment: ah cool, yes, I can change toggle to CTRL+/. That will help me at least with the toggle part!

Comment: What about just recording a macro of `CTRL+Q`, `Down` and bind that to `CTRL+/`?

Comment: perfect, I recorded a macro with 'Toggle' and then 'cursor down' and saved that macro as CTRL+/. Works perfect! Thanks @jmalenfant